# Counterexamples related to a convergent positive series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence such that $a_n > 0$ for all $n ≥ 1$ and $\sum_1^\infty$$a_n$
>   converges.
>
> Give
>   counterexamples to the following claims where $b_n$ =
>   $a_{n+1}$/$a_n$
>
> (a) $a_n ≤ 1$ for all $n ≥ 1$.
>
> (b) The sequence ${a_n}$ is non-increasing.
>
> (c) $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$ exists.
>
> (d) If $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$ exists, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n < 1$.
>
> (e) The sequence ${b_n}$ is bounded.
>
> (f) If $\limsup_{n\to \infty}b_n$ exists, then $\limsup_{n\to \infty}b_n\leq 1$.

My attempt: $2/n^3$ works for (a) and (d). I would really appreciate help for the other counter-examples.

Comment: I came up with an answer for part (b) as well, so I'm now just looking for help on (c), (e), and (f). My proposed solution isn't a counterexample for these cases, I believe.

Comment: You should add these to your post.

Comment: $a_n := \frac{1}{2^n}$ satisfies $\lim_n b_n = \frac{1}{2}$, so (c),(e),(f) are satisfied

Comment: @mathworker21 no, we have to come up with counter-examples for these statements.

Comment: @childishsadbino my bad. idk, just have $a_n$ alternate between $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$, or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. As regards (c) and (e) consider
$$a_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n+2^{-n}}{n^2}.$$
Can you modify it in order to obtain a counterexample for (f)?

Comment: I apologize, but I do not immediately see how I can modify your example to get a counterexample for (f).

Comment: @childishsadbino For example replace the numerator of the given $a_n$ with $2+(-1)^n$

Comment: Makes sense now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For (c), consider "merging" two convergent series:
$$
a_{2n} = \frac 1{3^n}, a_{2n-1}= \frac 1{2^n}, 
$$
then 
$$
\varlimsup b_n = +\infty, \varliminf b_n = 0. 
$$

Comment: This should serve as a counter-example for (e) as well, right?

Comment: Yeah.${{{{{{}}}}}}$